# order multiple rides with Lyft API?

Tags: lyft-api

I have a client that needs to be able order multiple rides for their customers. Is there any component of the API that would allow their single business appID to order, and pay for, these types of rides? Sometimes they would need to order two or three rides at once or have rides overlap each other.

Using a single user/token (similar to the Lyft app itself) doesn't work because once a ride is in progress that token is not usable again until the 1st ride is over.

Answer (score 1):

Lyft does have a set of APIs they call Concierge APIs. It's basically an API for booking rides on behalf of someone such as a call center agent getting a Lyft for a customer.

The APIs allow a single token to book multiple rides. It's worth noting that a given passenger name + phone number is considered a unique user and cannot have multiple rides booked, if that's what you're looking for.

You'll need to reach out to Lyft to get access to the APIs and documentation.